# Get from 2 inputs and replace at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two textareas inp1 and inp2, i'd like to get the input from those two text areas and add eatch input in it's position on the same paragraph that will be displayed on a div named "disp1".

I am already able to do that with a single input from only one input(inp1) textarea, but i don't really know how to do it for both at the same time.

here's my working code for one input : http://jsfiddle.net/1rsqn8g5/

```js
$('#inp1').on('input', function(e) {
$("#disp1").html("heloo, this is the word you entered:" + $(this).val() + "</br>Thanks");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea id="inp1" rows="4" cols="50" name="inp1"></textarea></br></br>


<a id="disp1" target="_blank">  </a>
```

I'd like to combine both textareas in one output container, for example i enter the word "Silicon" in the first textarea and "valley" in the second and get a text like this :

you entered the words : silicon and valley.

thank you

Comment: Not clear if you want one output to combine both textarea values or each textarea has it's own output container. Please show example along with expected results

Comment: Hello charlietfl, yes i'd like to combine both textareas in one div/paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const intro = "you entered the words: ";
const outro = "</br>Thanks";
let input1 = '';
let input2 = '';

$('#inp1, #inp2').on('input', function update(e) {
  if (e.currentTarget.id === 'inp1') {
    input1 = e.currentTarget.value;
  } else {
    input2 = e.currentTarget.value;
  }
  $("#disp1").html(intro + '<br>' + input1 + ' and ' + input2 + outro);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea id="inp1" rows="4" cols="50" name="inp1"></textarea></br>
</br>
<textarea id="inp2" rows="4" cols="50" name="inp1"></textarea></br>
</br>


<a id="disp1" target="_blank"> </a>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, would it be possible to make that happen in the JS code i provided please?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Something like "$('#inp1,#inp2').on('input', function(e)..."

Comment: If this solves your problem, be sure to click on the ✓ to accept the answer.

Comment: Hello, i'm stuck again... would it be possible to show me how to do it for 3 or more inputs please